# Create an Instance of A Class in WordPress's Ajax Callback Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am having trouble trying to create an instance of a class in my `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_test` callback function. Which looks like this:

```
function my_test()
{

  require_once (WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my-plugin/includes/class-my-test.php');

  // instantiate
  $obj = new classname(); //error thrown here

  die();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_test', 'my_test' );
```

I am getting a console error `jquery.js?ver=1.12.3:4 POST http://localhost/domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

My Javascript/Jquery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

        var data = {
            action: 'my_test'
        };

        // Ajax call
        $( target ).load(myWP.ajaxurl,
            data,
            function(){
                // alert('success.');
        });

    });

});
```

I have also tried this using a normal Ajax call and everything works fine. I have `echo`d a random string from `my_test()` to see if it was being called correctly and it is. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: General debugging advice: Look in the network panel of chrome or safari to find what's different between your working request and this broken one.

Comment: I think you have write correct code but no sure in your class file. You can check before without ajax to properly working. add_action( 'init', 'my_test' ); give output without any error.

Comment: When you tested with regular ajax was it also POST? Or GET? When using `load()` with data object it will create POST

Comment: Thanks for the debugging advice! That helped me narrow down my error. I found the error in my `php_error_log` and it was a namespace issue with the theme I was using. I had to change `$obj = new classname();` to `$obj = new \classname();` to tell PHP that the class `classname` is in the global namespace. Thanks again. =)

Comment: Could you post that as an answer?